# FPDF / How to make display correctly

Tags: php, download, fpdf

I'm using the fpdf library to output a pdf from html. The .pdf is being created because I can email it to myself and it arrives in the correct format but if I want to download the .pdf as an option without emailing, the output is illegible. The output appears in a browser window(see attached screen shot) and I'm unsure how to fix this issue.

I've also attached a screenshot of how we have our report options set up. 1. HTML 2. PDF 3. Download 4. Email  -- the HTML and Email options work, the PDF and Download options do not. I'm focusing on the Download option in this question.

This is the output code that I've tried to test out but no luck

```
//$pdf->Output("D","D:/example2.pdf");
//$content = $pdf->Output("","S");
//$pdf->Output(); //Outputs on browser screen

//Outputs on browser screen
$pdf->Output();
//echo file_get_contents($pdf);
//readfile($pdf);
```

- the $pdf->Output();  is generating the illegible code the readfile
- echo and  file_get_contents throw errors
- the $pdf->Output(...  gives  me an error that says Incorrect Output
  Destination (see attached    screenshot)

Need guidance -- thanks for any help. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

here is the full code:

```
 <?php

    $m_header = '<link href="shared/report.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">';
    $m_body_tag = ' scroll=no';
    require_once($DOCUMENT_ROOT."inc/top-2.inc.php");

    $i_get_sid = isset($_GET["sid"]) ? (int)$_GET["sid"] : $i_sid;

    $i_get_pass = isset($_GET["a"]) ? $_GET["a"] : $_SESSION['r_pass'];
    $i_get_pass = addslashes($i_get_pass);

    $i_pdf_file_url = 'report.php?sid='.$i_get_sid.'&a='.urlencode($i_get_pass).'&b=/report.pdf';

    echo '<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width="100%">';
    echo '<tr vAlign=top><td height=7><img src="images/1x1.gif" width=1 height=7></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr height=28 style="background: url(images/bookm-bg.gif) repeat-x"><td width="100%"><nobr>';
    echo '<img src="images/1x1.gif" width=5 height=1><a href="report.php?sid='.$i_get_sid.'&a='.urlencode($i_get_pass).'"><img src="images/bookm-42.gif" width=67 height=28 border=0></a><img src="images/bookm-s1.gif" width=10 height=28 border=0><img src="images/bookm-51.gif" width=65 height=28 border=0>&nbsp;<a href="report.php?sid='.$i_get_sid.'&a='.urlencode($i_get_pass).'&b=/report.pdf"><img src="images/button-downloadpdf.gif" width=80 height=28 border=0></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="report.php?sid='.$i_get_sid.'&a='.urlencode($i_get_pass).'&b=email"><img src="images/button-emailpdf.gif" width=80 height=28 border=0></a>';
    echo '</nobr></td><td><nobr><font style="font-size: 10px;"><a href="javascript:window.close();">Close Window</a>&nbsp;</font></nobr></td></tr></table>';



(This is what I added as a workaround)echo '<p><a href="'.$i_pdf_file_url.'" name="plugin" width=100% height=100% fullscreen=yes style="position: absolute;">Click Here to open the PDF</p>';

(This is what should display the PDF in the browser but wont' work)
echo '<p><embed type="application/pdf" src="'.$i_pdf_file_url.'" name="plugin" width=100% height=100% fullscreen=yes style="position: absolute;"></p>';


    require_once($DOCUMENT_ROOT."inc/btm-2.inc.php");

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm):

> Destination where to send the document. It can be one of the following:
>
> - I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.
> - D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
> - F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
> - S: return the document as a string.
>
> The default value is I.

If you want to force download with given name, create a link that points to your pdf script and use this:

```
$pdf->Output("__name__","F");
```

If you want to display pdf for preview use this:

```
$pdf->Output("__name__","I");
```

and in your html inside **PDF** tab use *iframe* to embed pdf:

```
<iframe src="pdf_preview.php" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

There are other ways to do this, but this should be the easest.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Here's the code on the page that is supposed to display the report on the page. I did try the iframe option (see commented out code) but wasn't able to get it to work. 

echo '<p><embed type="application/pdf" src="'.$i_pdf_file_url.'" name="plugin" width=100% height=100% fullscreen=yes style="position: absolute;"></p>';

Comment: this is the iframe code I tried >>  //echo '<p><iframe type="application/pdf" target="_parent" src="'.$i_pdf_file_url.'" name="plugin" width=100% height=100% fullscreen=yes style="position: absolute;"></iframe></p>';

Comment: @user3434928 Can you update the question with your code? It's unreadable in the comment.

Comment: The question has been updated / thanks for the help (and sorry for the delay - busy time of year!)